# It is necessary to load on one domain name pages from different web servers

Tags: apache2

It is necessary to load on one domain name pages from different web servers (apache2). For example, www.somesite.ru/page/ loads from server 12.34.56.78 and www.somesite.ru/another_page/ loads from another server 12.34.56.79.

How to make, what it would work?

Comment: is this static? ie /page you want always loaded from ip .78 and /another_page from .79 ?

Comment: No. There are many diffenent sections, which should be loaded from different servers

Comment: Why do you want this? To limit bandwidth usage, to integrate multiple pages into one, to limit storage space?

Comment: What two projects to unite in one. different subdomens does not approach

Comment: Richard, I have not correctly understood at first. One page address will always have only one ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

on ip .78 I used mod_rewrite + mod_proxy.

RewriteRule ^/(another_page)/?$ http://www2.somesite.ru/$1 [P]

www2.somesite.ru has ip .79